# lxml namespaces defined multiple times

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces

I am switching from python xml to lxml. I faced that lxml has rather strict policy towards namespaces.

I want to produce a xml with multiple redundant xmlns:ns0 namespace declaration. However, lxml strips this namespaces from child Elements.

How can I define redundant namespaces via lxml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="some URI" xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Body>
        <ns0:getLabelResponseElement>
            <ns0:result>
                <ns1:statusMessage xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"></ns1:statusMessage>
            </ns0:result>
        </ns0:getLabelResponseElement>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: I expect there a good reason why you need these redundant namespace declarations? Please add your reason(s) to your question - otherwise it is difficult to know what to suggest.

Comment: Presumably this is because the recipient uses some home-brew approach to parsing the XML. I'm afraid we get a lot of this on StackOverflow: people who try to process XML by hand, then find that they can only process a rather peculiar subset of XML, leading to questions from people who need to generate this rather peculiar subset. All caused by people not appreciating the importance of standards conformance.

Comment: @kimbert the reason is to reproduce a response made by legacy Java service.

Comment: Sorry to keep questioning but...if these xmlns attributes are _redundant_ then why do you need to reproduce them? The XML is valid either way. There must be a business reason for this, because there is no technical reason that I can think of.

Comment: @kimbert this response XML might be parsed by regex. I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, lxml.etree doesn't allow to add redundant namespace declaration in child Elements since this violates XML standards. So, even if you explicitly redeclare namespace in child element lxml wouldn't add it in final XML.
Unlike lxml, python xml.etree.ElementTree library allows redundant xml namespace declaration.

Comment: What is "python-xml library"?

Comment: @mzjn https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html

Comment: That's not one library, that is a whole bunch of very different XML modules. But never mind, it probably does not matter.

Comment: @mzjn makes sense. I updated my answer